# Sqlite data gets cleared while using coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my application I am using Coredata.At some particular scenario all the data's get cleared (Not sure if the db is getting deleted).I am trying to find the scenario for the past one week but I am not able to find the root cause.I am also using Crashlytics in my app,but didn’t get any crash report.I haven’t faced this issue in debug mode but few of the Beta testers reported this issue.
    I am posting this to get some direction on the scenarios where Coredata behaves as mentioned above

Comment: Can you provide us your code?

Comment: There's absolutely no scenario where this would be considered normal, unless you're intentionally deleting the files. You need to describe your app and add some code before anyone will be able to help.